# Firebase V8 to V9 conversion

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code snippet here that I want to convert from Firebase V8 to V9, but I can't seem to find the correct syntax. Thanks for anyone's help!

```
const [orders, setOrders] = useState()

db
 .collection("users")
 .doc(user?id)
 .collection("orders")
 .orderBy("created", "desc")
 .onSnapshot(snapshot => (
    setOrders(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
        id: doc.id,
        data: doc.data()
     }))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onSnapshot()` is a top level function Modular SDK and so are other methods used in this code snippet. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
const colRef = collection(db, `users/${user?.uid}/orders`);
const q = query(colRef, orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'));

onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
  // ...
})
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) for more information.